# asp.net 5 mvc 6 identity with restricted database backend

Tags: database, stored-procedures, identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use MVC6 Identity 3 with a database that provides no interface to lookup users. It does however allow me to send username and password to a stored procedure and in return I get an access id and real name of the user. I cannot get anything else without being authenticated and even with, I cannot query other users by id.

Now, know this, is it possible to use the Identity framework with a custom UserManager to perform the password check and retrieving the user details?

I have already overridden the CheckPasswordAsync method that allows me to check the username and password:

```
    public override Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        bool success = false;
        // query the database via stored procedure (only Login supported)
        var result = _dataAccess.Login(user.Login, password);
        if (result != null)
        {
            //user.UserId = result.id;
            //user.FirstNames = result.first_names;
            //user.LastName = result.last_name;
            success = true;
        }
        return Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => success);
    }
```

The commented lines are wishful thinking... I'd like to access those field from my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // get the current user details and return them.
                // but how?
                var userDetails = { ... };
                return Ok(userDetails);
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            }
            else
            {
                return HttpUnauthorized();
            }
        }
        return HttpUnauthorized();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get user details by calling `_userManager.FindByLoginAsync()` or use `_userManager.Users` property and simply retrieve user using linq query. You will be able to get your ApplicationUser bu that.

If you would like to store/get user information using stored procedures then you've to override UserStore. Here is short overview:

[image]

Take a look here for detailed informations: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

Comment: Hmm but the only place I have the user details at hand is in CheckPasswordAsync. I have to store them somewhere for FindByLoginAsync to find them.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand correctly you question - are you using EntityFramework and store identity there or not? If yes then EF will handle this for you. When the database is created based on you DB context (which should inherit from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>) then EF will create proper tables in the database. They won't be available in the context buy you can access those data by using UserManager, RoleManager and SignInManager for example.

Comment: I am not using the EntityFramework as I do not have table access. The only access I have is a store procedure that, when given username and password, will give me authenticated user details or an authentication error.

Comment: Ahhh, ok! In that case all you need to do is to override UserStore and RoleStore. Create those classes based on IUserStore<ApplicationUser" and IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>. Those classes are responsible for accessing database tables and retrieving data for UserManager and RoleManager. When you'll override them you will be able to use stored procedures to retrieve data.

Comment: Thats what I though, but no method in userstore or rolestore accept a password and hence I cannot return anything from the database using these methods. Only in the UserManager did I find a method that accepted a password, CheckPasswordAsync, and I have shown the method in my code above.

Comment: If you want to check the password then yes - change CheckPasswordAsync. But if you wan't to get user details using UserManager and your stored procedures then you've to override default UserStore.

Comment: So I have to call ApplicationUserStore.CreateUserAsync in ApplicationUserManager.CheckPasswordAsync to store the user details I get from the database login call? It seems to next to impossible to use Identity to handle logins when all I have is this one store procedure. Have I missed a requirement to use Identity that I MUST have access to the complete user table? Our DB admin will not give that access. :-/

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Reading the information given by your link, I have come to the conclusion that I cannot use the Identity framework at all. It simply requires more data access than I can provide. I have absolutely no unauthorized database access and the only authorized information I can get (by providing login and password) is the current users database id and name. There is no possible way to implement the FindByIdAsync or FindByNameAsync as no password is present. I will have to revert to using Session state instead. Too bad, as Identity seems great.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is no solution. The Identity framework requires some way to access all user data, i.e. FindByName/FindById. These two method need to be created or authentication cannot happen. My database cannot provide this service and as such, Identity framework is not going to happen.

The working solution is to drop Identity and use Cookie authentication directly and that works as intended.